# Parent mesh scaling affecting child mesh

Tags: three.js, dat.gui

I'm playing around with my Three.js project which is suppose to let users adjust a self-designed table.

The issue is that the Height of the table(surface) affects the height of the legs when adjusting. I want the height of the legs remain the same when the height of the surface(parent) is adjusted.

I'm using the 'Dat.gui' library for user-input adjustments

`tableBoard.scale.y = this.title.TableDepth; //This affects the child`

**The surface is the parent and the legs are childs to the surface**
[image: Table]

Can someone point me in the direction of how i can adjust the height of my surface without affecting the children mesh?

Comment: You're gonna have to group your table differently. Use a `THREE.Group()` as a parent element to contain all 5 parts, so you can scale the table-top independently without affecting the legs. As a side-note, have you considered [taking an intro to Three.js course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oFvqLfRnsU)? It seems you come back daily asking for help with the next small step on your project. You'd benefit greatly from learning [the essentials through a tutorial](https://discoverthreejs.com/), then you can spend time building without needing to stop to ask for help along every step of the way.

Comment: Thank you for your response Marquizzo. I've taken several courses, including the one you just recommended but my questions asked are subjects that are never talked about in these course, therefor my questions here on Stack. Apologies for the spam, but I've found this library quite fascinating and the help and knowledge I've been given here on Stack has truly helped me upon my path.

Comment: Ok, fair enough... Let me know if nesting the individual elements inside a `Three.Group()` helped solve your problem.